# Can OpenScap generate 1 report compiling multiple results?

Tags: openscap

Sample command to evaluate:

```bash
$ oscap xccdf eval --profile xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_rht-ccp --results scan-xccdf-results.xml /usr/share/xml/scap/ssg/content/ssg-rhel7-ds.xml
```

Sample command to remediate:

```bash
$ oscap xccdf remediate --results scan-xccdf-results.xml scan-xccdf-results.xml
```

Sample command to generate report:

```bash
$ oscap xccdf generate report xccdf-results.xml > report-xccdf.html
```

Can OpenSCAP generate 1 report for multiple results (from different hosts/servers) in HTML, Excel or CSV?

for example:

```bash
$ oscap xccdf generate report xccdf-results01.xml,xccdf-results02.xml,xccdf-results03.xml > report-xccdf.html
$ oscap xccdf generate report xccdf-results01.xml,xccdf-results02.xml,xccdf-results03.xml > report-xccdf.xlsx
$ oscap xccdf generate report xccdf-results01.xml,xccdf-results02.xml,xccdf-results03.xml > report-xccdf.csv
```

This would be useful to compile 100s of reports in 1 view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, it can't do it. It only can generate report from a single scan on a single machine. People usually use Red Hat Satellite to manage OpenSCAP scans for multiple machines.